# How to create a DataGrid in Flex?

Tags: flex4, flex-datagrid

Can someone tell me how I can create a nested row in a flex datagrid, like the diagram below? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `AdvancedDataGrid` control. See [description](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=advdatagrid_02.html) and [API documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/AdvancedDataGrid.html) for it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="mainADG"  >
<mx:groupedColumns>
    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn />
    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn />
    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn />

    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumnGroup >
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn />
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn />
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn />
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn />
    </mx:AdvancedDataGridColumnGroup>

</mx:groupedColumns></mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
```